# Sound card diagnosis

Tags: windows-10, audio, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell Optiplex 780 running Win 10. When I first started using it sound was OK, but now the volume level is so low through my external speakers that the only way I hear sound is through the built-in speaker on the sound board.

Headphones work just fine.

Could this be a problem with the sound board?

Is there a stand-alone, free utility that I could download & boot from to test the sound card? I've run Dell diagnostics, but it finds nothing wrong.

I managed to get Linux to boot with help from another forum. Linux did not produce sound either. I guess that means there's a hardware error, but is it the sound card or my speakers or a speaker cable? How do I find out?

Answer (score 0):

I installed new speakers today. They work! I guess the old ones just wore out.

I'm not sure what this says about the sound card, however, since these speakers get power & the sound signal through a USB port. The old ones used USB for power only with a separate cable for sound. I suppose something could be wrong with the sound port.